# Python "If" + "And" conditioning ignores one. Code in post

Tags: python, if-statement

Basically trying to learn Python and I was doing the hackerrank 30 day challenge. 
Task 
Given an integer, n , perform the following conditional actions:

If n is odd, print ok
If n is even and in the inclusive range of 2 to 5, print nok

```
n = 4
if n in range(2,5) and type(n/2) == int:
  print ("ok")        
else:
    print ("nok")
```

it prints "nok" no matter what n is.

Comment: By the way, `range(2,5)` is not an inclusive range of 2 to 5 in Python. It should be `range(2,6)` so that 5 is included in the range.

Comment: I noticed that shortly after. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Python 3 `/` always returns a float (`isinstance(4 / 2, int)` is `False` since `4 / 2` returns `2.0`).

Since you are essentially checking for the parity of `n`, check it explicitly:

```
... and n % 2 == 0:
```

Comment: Thank you, I had no idea it always returned a float. This solved my issue.

Comment: `if n in range(2,5,2):`

Answer (score 0):

Because, n/2 = 2.0 not 2, i.e division returns a `float` not `int` here are some ways to check it :

```
n in range(2,5) and n % 2 == 0
#or 
n in range(2,5) and n & 1 != 1  #because, every odd number has last bit 1
```

Comment: Use `n % 2 == 0`.Using `%` has better performance, readability and clarity.

Comment: Thanks guys! Appreciate the help.